# Dynamically knowing all the subclasses of a superclass

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Say I have a class to model my customers

```
class Customer 
{
    public static customerType = 'customer';
}
```

And a subclass `class CorporateCustomer extends Customer` to model my corporate customers. Presently I have three subclasses

```
class AlphaCustomer extends CorporateCustomer {...}
class BetaCustomer  extends CorporateCustomer {...}
class GammaCustomer extends CorporateCustomer {...}
```

Each subclass of `Customer` overwrites the `customerType` property. This property is used when my model is loaded into my database.

Of course, as my business evolves new subclasses of `CorporateCustomer` might be added.

Now in another part of my application, I have a variable called `currentCustomerType` and I need to determine if there exists a subclass `c` of `CorporateCustomer` such that `c::customerType` is equal to `currentCustomerType`.

How would you do this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If you need to know if a JSON string is a representation of a `CorporateCustomer` class, wouldn't you just deserialize it as such, and see if the deserialization works?

Comment: I guess my question was misleading. I'm not actually dealing with an faithful JSON representation of a Customer object, I'm just dealing with some arbitrary json that has this field that originated from the Customer.customerType property. The question still stands though, I'd like to dynamically (and in a nice way) access all the possible customerType options under `CorporateCustomer`.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Do you think you can edit your question to provide an example of a JSON file, and to say what exactly is your requirement? Re-reading the question for the fourth time, I'm under impression that you explained your approach, without explaining the actual problem you are trying to solve. That's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/147298).

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko I tried to strip it down to the bare minimum with the recent edit. Does it make better sense now?

Comment: Is this Java? Maybe you could try the reflection library mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520339) to examine the classes themselves, rather than a custom property.

Comment: @gen: I'm sorry, but it still looks the same, and in its current form would be more on-topic on StackOverflow. The problem is that even if somebody tells you the *technical* solution, you may be missing some good advice if you don't explain the actual requirements. The answer by candied_orange below also goes in this way, I believe.

Comment: You're asking how to proceed with a design which is already seriously flawed. The answer is to back up, describe the actual problem you're trying to solve as if you hadn't written any code at all. It's frustrating, but it will let people help you and maybe result in a more effective base design.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question, or is this just asking about the factory pattern?  I'd hardly call that a "seriously flawed" design - it's the usually way to deserialize JSON (for example) in a polymorphic way.

Comment: Perhaps you could interpret *seriously flawed* as *a potential source of bugs*? The most common mistake might be to add a new subclass but forget to update the logic which finds subclasses based on type.

Comment: What happens when someone creates `private class HiddenCustomer extends CorporateCustomer {...}`?

Comment: I would not go as far as jumping to the conclusion that you are on the wrong path and should do X instead. There is too little information for that. I do wonder what is so special about your different customers that could not be modeled with plain properties. Inheritance is not something to be avoided as some claim but it may be overkill and not very helpful to your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the OO tags you put on your question, what you’re trying to do isn’t object oriented. If it was you’d be hiding types not asking about them.

Now sure sometimes you need to have relationships between things that you can query.  But that’s not types. That’s containers. Use those for this. Doing this to the type system just makes a mess.

Comment: Well what I currently have is object oriented, and what I'd need to achieve you just cast as `not object oriented`. I guess I have an object oriented setup, and I'm trying to figure out how to achieve something given this setup. Hopefully as nicely as possible. And I agree, making a mess with types is something I'm trying to avoid, so I guess I'm looking for alternatives to that.

Comment: Work your requirement. Your question is imposing a solution. Figure out what you really need to achieve. Right now all you’re asking is how to do it this way. If that’s all you ask all I can say is don’t do it that way.

Comment: There's only one question I'm seeking to find an answer for and it doesn't impose a solution at all. It asks _"How would you maintain a list of the customerType property on the various subclasses of the CorporateCustomer class?"_

Comment: Don’t call it object oriented. OO code doesn’t have a type property.

Comment: "What you’re trying to do isn’t object oriented." - that is probably correct, but "object oriented" is not automatically  "the only right way". There may be a situation which may justify exactly what the OP has written.

Comment: @DocBrown very true.  But please note the tags on the question.

Answer (score 4):

- Avoid inheritance, try composition.
- If you must be able to detect the type, perhaps try virtual members, that can be overridden in extending classes.

There is a problem, but it's not what you might think. You are asking how to **abuse** the type system, and the answer you will (correctly) be getting is **not to do so**. The actual problem is that this is the **short answer** and the long answer is **pretty long**!

> "How would you maintain a list of the customerType property on the
>   various subclasses of the CorporateCustomer class?"

Your insistence means that the long answer has to be **even longer**. Well, I won't try to give the long answer, but at least, let me try to set some things straight.

There are many ways you can use to **abuse the type system** so that you can have your way. If you insist on doing that (maybe you just need a very quick fix), then:

```cs
//c#, but easily portable to java

class Customer
{
    protected static List<string> m_availableCustomerTypes = new List<string>();

    public virtual string CustomerType => "Plain Customer";

    static Customer()
    {
        m_availableCustomerTypes.Add("Plain Customer");
    }

    //Gets you all the available customer types. Exposes the protected variable
    //but only as an IEnumerable.
    public static IEnumerable<string> AllCustomerTypes => m_availableCustomerTypes;
}

class CorporateCustomer : Customer
{

    public override string CustomerType => "Corporate Customer";

    static CorporateCustomer
    {
        m_availableCustomerTypes.Add("Corporate Customer");
    }
}

//etc...
```

I.e. you can create a static list in the root class of the Customer hierarchy, and **not forget to "register" the customer type inside each static constructor, by adding it to the base-most list**. This way, you can iterate the `AllCustomerTypes` list from any place within your codebase and you should have all the types, just **don't forget to add them in each derived class' static constructor**.

This solution **officially sucks**, but [a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-man-s-gotta-do-what-a-man-s-gotta-do), right? Well, this is the tip of the iceberg. The rest of the **long answer** I was talking about earlier has to do with why this is a terrible idea. And even if it never ever ends up causing you any trouble, **it remains a terrible idea**. Why?

- It accustoms you to a very bad practice that
- robs you of the true abstraction power of object-oriented programming, which lies in
- not needing to know implementation details of the objects you are juggling in the location you are juggling, as long as
- you have clearly and properly defined interaction semantics (cleanly defined interfaces for your types).

The moment you need to check the type of an object, you are creating a location within the codebase, which will be **excessively fragile**. The answer I provided above fails if someone tries to extend your codebase and forgets to "register" the customer type. So **only you** know the "secrets" of your classes and, who knows, you may forget it in the future. How "empowering" is that? The idea is to let the type system **remind you** when you are trying to do something you did not intend to in the first place.

If you happen to ask what you should have done, the answer is, skip inheritance, use composition. Why do you need 10 strongly-typed `Customer` alternatives anyway? At the **very least**, use an `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're looking for is the factory pattern.  You have plain data (JSON in this case), and you want to deserialize it in a polymorphic way.  The determining factor in this case is a static field, but that's incidental.

So you'd have a factory method like:
Customer CreateCustomer(string json);

And that would return the appropriate subclass of Customer.  How?  Usually a switch statement.  But you could also use reflection to scan through the subclasses, if you don't mind the performance cost.

Comment: The [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) is exactly what I was going to propose.

Comment: A factory will give you the JSON of 1 subtype. It will not give you a list of all subtypes.

Comment: I made some changes to my question to better suit @Arseni's taste, and I'm now content  with getting one subtype even. So I find this answer valuable, thanks Errorsatz for posting.

Comment: @gen, a factory will give you an object of a Customer subclass based on the arguments you pass in and the classes know to the factory, or an error (or whatever you decide) if no known subclass can be instantiated from the arguments. Does that meet your needs?

Comment: The factory will also need to be a (possibly speculative or proactive) class loader. It will need to load the class (for the Customer subtype) even if that class hasn't been loaded yet. To do so, the factory will need to either attempt to load a class given a string, or by proactively scanning a specific class-file folder for new class-files or changes to jars.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I need to determine if there exists a subclass c of CorporateCustomer...

This sounds like a *cross-cutting concern*, your problem spans across the whole application. These types of problems are addressed by **aspect-oriented programming** (AOP). To get all subclasses of a certain class, you would typically query the class as `CorporateCustomer+`. In the aspect advice you can subsequently store a (preferably weak reference) `Map<String, Class>`, where the keys are `customerType`

Answer (score 1):

> Now in another part of my application, I have a variable called currentCustomerType and I need to determine if there exists a subclass c of CorporateCustomer such that c::customerType is equal to currentCustomerType.

There is a simple and straightforward solution to this problem, which does not need "reflection" and works in most OO programming languages:

- in the part of the application where the subclasses are defined, make a list of `CorporateCustomer` objects which holds exactly one  "prototypical" object of each available subclass.
- pass that list to that "other part" of your application where `currentCustomerType` exists
- now simply iterate over the list to check if there is an instance `c` in the list for which `c.customerType` matches `currentCustomerType`.

If you found such an instance `c` and use it, for example, to create other instances of the same type by "cloning", then you have rediscovered the well known [Prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Of course, there are some assumptions in my answer, first and foremost that there is a well-defined list of subtypes in some area of your code from which it is not too hard to create and maintain the mentioned list. You have to check for yourself if your system meets this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might design your software with [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) in mind (e.g. using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux, or [Java class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) if using the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)), to ease its customization or extendability.

If you have plugins (or any other runtime [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) facilities) you cannot dynamically know all the subclasses of a given class, because that set will vary with time, since a freshly loaded plugin can define new classes.

> Dynamically knowing all the subclasses of a superclass

... it is not possible if the code changes (e.g. by plugins being loaded) at runtime. Unless your programming language object model is as powerful as the [ObjVLisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjVlisp) model.

You might get inspiration from [Qt](https://qt.io/) object model and metaclasses.

Your many variant of customers issue smells like a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Read [Abadi and Cardelli *A theory of objects*](http://lucacardelli.name/TheoryOfObjects.html) book. Notice that [typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) and [objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) are concepts in tension (and have very different definitions: [Ocaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) object model is not [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) or [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) or [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)) or [CLOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) one). Be aware of [agent-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model) programming, and of [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) concepts.

With multi-threading and garbage collection, things become even more complex. Read also the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

See also the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project, closely related to your concerns.